# Can I get an approximation for $(1-x)^n$, where $0<x<1$, $n\gg 1$?

Tags: approximation

I know it can be done when $xn \ll 1 $, but what about the cases when $xn \gt 1$ ?

My best try is to use sth like:
\begin{align*}
(1-x)^n  &=  \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}\left( \begin{array}{c}
n  \\
j \end{array} \right)(-x)^j 
\end{align*}

However, when $n$ is very large, calculation of the binomial coefficients may exceed computational capability of available tools such as mathwork, so I am stuck.

Comment: If $xn$ is not too large, you can approximate $(1-x)^n\approx e^{-xn}$

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Could you sketch the derivation?

Comment: Why do you want to approximate $(1-x)^{n}$?

Comment: $x$ is actually the possibility that an event would happen at one time instance, $(1-x)^n$ is the possibility that the event would not happen at $n$ time instance, and that is what I want ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0<x<1$ we have $\log (1-x)^n=-n\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x^j/j$. Taking $k$ large enough that $n\sum_{j>k}x^j/j<r$, and let $\sum_{j=1}^{k}x^j/j=F(x,k). $ We have $e^ {-n F(x,k)}e^{-r}<(1-x)^n<e^{-n F(x,k)}.$ Of course $k$ depends on both $n$ and $x$ for any given $r>0$, but given $y\in (0,x)$ we can use the same $k$.

Comment: Are you missing an $e^r$ on the right side of the inequality?

Comment: @videlity . No. $(1-x)^n<e^{-nF(x,k)}\iff $ $n\log (1-x)<-nF(x,k) \iff$ $ \log (1-x)<-F(x,k) \iff$ $ -\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x^j/j<-\sum_{j=1}^kx^j/j.$

Answer (score 1):

I was also interested in the same question. Here is an answer that uses ideas from the answer and comment above. Since $\log(1-x)^n = -n\sum_{j=1}^\infty x^j/j$, then we have 
$$\begin{align}(1-x)^n &= \exp\left(-n\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j}\right) \\&=\exp(-nx).\exp\left(-n\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^j}{j}\right) 
\end{align}$$
Now let's find the absolute error of approximating $(1-x)^n$ with $e^{-nx}$. Subtracting $e^{-nx}$ from both sides and taking absolute values we get
$$\begin{align}|(1-x)^n-e^{-nx}| &= |e^{-nx}(e^{-n\sum_{j=2}^\infty x^j/j}-1)|
\\&= e^{-nx}(1-e^{-n\sum_{j=2}^\infty x^j/j})
\\&<e^{-nx}
\end{align}
$$
which tells us that the error in this approximation is bounded by $e^{-nx}$ (which goes to 0 as $nx\to \infty$).